# Using numpy genfromtxt to load data with special characters as missing values

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to load data with "#" as missing value

[image: data]

I am using genfromtxt

```
genfromtxt("data.txt",missing_values="#",filling_values=0)
```

but I keep getting the following error

> raise ValueError(errmsg)
>   ValueError: Some errors were detected !
>       Line #25 (got 1 columns instead of 5)

I have tried to fill the missing values as can be seen in the code above but keeping this error

Answer (score 1):

The default `comments` argument of [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) is `#`, so you need to change that.  Also, make `filling_values` the string `"0"`.

For example,

```
In [30]: !cat data_missing.txt 
1.23e+00 4.56e+01 2.00e+00
7.89e+01 #.##e+## 3.00e+00

In [31]: a = np.genfromtxt("data_missing.txt",
   ....:                   comments=None,
   ....:                   missing_values="#.##e+##",
   ....:                   filling_values="0")

In [32]: a
Out[32]: 
array([[  1.23,  45.6 ,   2.  ],
       [ 78.9 ,   0.  ,   3.  ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column separator (I assume, in your case it is tabular):

```
genfromtxt(delimiter = "\t")
```

Also, your missing values are `missing_values="#.########e+##"`

Comment: it returns a 150x0 matrix instead of 150x5 and the data is replaced by nan, so the delimiter is not '\t' but spaces and with spaces it gives an error